# 14.04 Random Logouts

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, login-screen, crash, logout

Relates to the unsolved question #166687

I also am using chrome when the screen goes black and I'm at the login screen.
Everything I had open is now closed and my keyring was not unlocked at login.